# How to print a JPanel with swing components?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to  print a JPanel using java.awt.print.I want to print out a JPanel.I have tried the following code which consists of only one button.When printed it appears on the left corner of the page,but I need to print it in the original position as it appears on the screen.Is there way to set bounds to give an exact position?

enter code here

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.print.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class PrintButton extends JPanel implements
        Printable, ActionListener {

    JButton ok = new JButton("OK");

    public PrintButton() {
        ok.addActionListener(this);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        this.add(ok);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Print");
        frame.getContentPane().add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PrintButton();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        printJob.setPrintable(this);
        if (printJob.printDialog()) {
            try {
                printJob.print();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int index) throws
            PrinterException {

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        if (index >= 1) {
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        } else {

            ok.printAll(g2);
            return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Align your code for a better world.

Comment: Start by taking a look at [Printing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html) and inarticulate [Printing the Contents of a User Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/gui.html). The default position for printing tends be 0x0, you could try translating the graphics context before painting

Comment: The other problem you will face is paper doesn't translate well to the screen, that is, the size and aspect ratios don't tend to match well.  Java tends to render graphics to the screen at appropriately 72 dpi, but printers can have a much higher dpi

Comment: Thanks.Is there a way to change the default position(0X0) and place the components in different places.

Answer (score 4):

In your `print` method, you are only printing the button:

```
ok.printAll(g2);
```

To print the JPanel, you should call the printAll method of that JPanel:

```
this.printAll(g2);
```

If you want to be sure the panel fits on the page, you'll want to scale it using a Graphics2D transformation, based on the page size passed to you in the PageFormat object.

```
AffineTransform originalTransform = g2.getTransform();

double scaleX = pf.getImageableWidth() / this.getWidth();
double scaleY = pf.getImageableHeight() / this.getHeight();
// Maintain aspect ratio
double scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
g2.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
g2.scale(scale, scale);
this.printAll(g2);

g2.setTransform(originalTransform);
```

Note: I haven't actually tested this.

Comment: Thanks.I called the method panel.printAll(g2),and it works fine.But the problem is that it shows only a part of my form which fits to one page.I think I need to do a scaling so that whole form fits to the page.How can I scale my form before calling printAll method?

Comment: Updated answer.  Add Graphics2D transformation using information in the PageFormat passed to your print method.